# Access Array elements from one component to another Vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, components, vuejs2, custom-component

I am trying to create a shopping cart and I have a component that lists all my items. When I select 'Add to cart' button, it adds an item to a dummy cart I have displayed in that same component. I would like to know how can I make that array accessible to App.vue where my real shopping cart is?

This is the item class:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> 0 - Items<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu">
          <li> {{ cart }} </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I get the {{ cart }} array to display whatever option I select to the cart. I want to do the same in App.vue so basically have the same cart but in different component with the functionality for the addToCart will stay separate to App.vue

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider using Vuex with your project, it's meant for this purpose. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look. Is that the only option available? I didn't think it would be such a big issue

Comment: It's the official state management tool, although technically you could use Redux. Vuex might sound confusing at first but it'll save you a ton of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of all you items is located inside you App component - you could use child -> parent communication via events (`this.$emit` and `v-on`).

Checkout this doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events